# Windows 7 hard drive mirroring with truecrypt system drive

Tags: windows-7, truecrypt, mirroring

I am setting up a new Windows 7 x64 workstation with 2 identical hard drives. The system drive is fully encrypted with truecrypt, and I would like to also encrypt the second drive.

What is my best option to mirror/shadow the entire system drive over to the second encrypted drive? Can I use Windows 7 mirrored volumes?

I would prefer not to buy a hardware RAID card, and I do not care if the mirror is 100% real time. I would be fine with backup software  that performs this process in the background.

Thanks!

Comment: Robocopy starting regularly?

Comment: I like the fact that robocopy is a light weight, built in tool to Windows. Would it perform well in the background? Could it launch without a terminal window popping up?

Comment: I think it could, look into the planned tasks section. You can give Windows tasks it executes regularly there. Like a cronjob.

Answer (score 2):

**RAID is for minimizing downtime because of disk failure.** It doesn't provide protection from higher-level errors such as accidental file deletion, etc. Plus, I've never used TrueCrypt's system encryption, but I think it's not so simple to build a RAID-like configuration with it.

So I think that you should use TrueCrypt's **system encryption on the first drive** and create an **encrypted volume on the second drive**. Then **create backups regularly** with either **Windows' built-in Backup tool** or a scheduled **[XCopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx)** (RoboCopy) job ([tutorial](http://www.design-ireland.net/article/Running_Scheduled_Backups_with_Xcopy)). You don't have to worry about encryption, because it's done on a lower level by the TrueCrypt "driver".

If you need a backup of your whole system, then the built-in tool is the one you should choose (it creates bootable VHD files) - or some kind of RAID. However, if you only need your data safe, then XCopy will do just as fine.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, too. (+) But you're missing something: Theres no Truecrypt file he could copy. The whole partition is encrypted with TrueCrypt.

Comment: I hope it answers your questions now @sinni800.

Comment: My main concern is disk failure. The optimal solution would be to have a bootable replica of the first drive, which may not be possible without RAID 1 mirroring? At the very least I just need to clone the data.

Comment: RAID-1 creates a bit-for-bit replica. XCopy and Windows Backup are not capable of that. But disk failure is not something that happens every day. For home a regular backup is a much better than RAID.

Comment: @KovBal now it's a complete solution! This is how I'd have done it too.